# ComponentOne DataGrid Default Filter is not working

Tags: datagrid, componentone

Here is my dataGrid xaml:

```
<c1datagrid:C1DataGrid x:Name="taskExecutionDetailC1DataGrid"
                               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                               SelectionMode="SingleCell"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=taskExecutionDetailDomainDataSource, Path=Data}"
                               AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                               CanUserFilter="True" c1:C1NagScreen.Nag="True" />
```

But, its not showing the filter icon (drop arrow) on hovering the header.

I have referenced C1.Silverlight. DataGrid.Filters dll.

Please Help. I have spent a lot of time on this grid, and now don't wanna leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using WCF RIA Services. When you bind C1DataGrid to a RIA Services DomainDataSource you will lose the built-in filtering functionality because RIA Services uses a different filtering approach than the standard CollectionView. To retain this functionality you will need to add the C1RiaAdapter to translate the filtering information to RIA. Check out the online documentation:
[wcf ria services databinding](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/C1DataGridSL/wcfriaservicesdatabinding.htm)

There's also a sample with filtering example available online here:
[C1DataGrid RIA](http://our.componentone.com/samples/silverlight-c1datagrid-3)